# Append to MySQL Results if 1 column in NOT IN the results

Tags: mysql, if-statement, union

I want to create a MyQSL Query similar to

```
SELECT person, city FROM mytable 
UNION 
SELECT 'BOB', 'Chicago' IF 'BOB' NOT IN (SELECT person FROM mytable);
```

If 'BOB' is not returned in the results, I want to append him to the results and list him as being in Chicago. If BOB does come back in the results, no matter what his location is, I do not want to append him as being in Chicago.

I can make this work if I exactly match the columns, but I will end up getting multiple results for BOB if he is listed as being somewhere other than Chicago.

```
SELECT person, city FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT 'BOB', 'Chicago'
```

but I do not want to match on the location. Just the person's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT person, city FROM mytable 
UNION 
SELECT 'BOB', 'Chicago' from dual
 where NOT exists (SELECT person FROM mytable WHERE person = 'BOB');
```

A more optimized version, that returns the same results

```
SELECT person, city FROM mytable WHERE person <> 'BOB'
UNION 
SELECT 'BOB', COALESCE((select city from mytable WHERE person = 'BOB'), 'Chicago') from dual
```

Comment: `dual` is just a convenience for people that like to specify always the table name, when there is not a concrete table to get data from. It is not required in mySql and MSSQL as it is in Oracle. However it is still required if you need to specify a WHERE. Example: `select 1` is the same as `select 1 from dual`, but `select 'ok' where 0=0` does not work, you need `dual` here, `select 'ok' from dual where 0=0`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite of your original query that should work:

```
SELECT person, city FROM mytable 
UNION 
SELECT 'BOB', 'Chicago' from dual where not exists (
  SELECT NULL FROM mytable where person = 'BOB'
);
```